# Strong Maximum Principle: every sequence $z_n\in U$ converging to $\partial U$ or $|z_n|\to\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, maximum-principle

Suppose $U$ is an open connected subset of the complex plane, and $f(z)$ is a non-constant holomorphic function on $U$. Suppose there exists  $M\geq0$ such that

$$ \varlimsup_{n\to \infty} |f(z_n)|\le M$$

for every sequence $z_n\in U$ converging to a point in $\partial U$ or $|z_n|\to\infty$. Prove that the $|f(z)| \lt M$ for all $z\in U$.

---

this problem is related to [Show holomorphic function bounded if limit of  |f(z)|  as  z→z0∈∂U  is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894386/show-holomorphic-function-bounded-if-limit-of-fz-as-z-rightarrow-z-0), but the answer seems not working, construct (by maximum modulus principle) a sequence $z_n$ with $|f(z_n)|> M$ is not true because $U$ may be Unbounded

How to get this?  also, does this conclusion follow if the assumption $|z_n|\to\infty$ is dropped ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Such a sequence must have at least one of a) a subsequence with $\lvert z_{n_k}\rvert \to \infty$, or b) a subsequence with $z_{n_k} \to z_0 \in \partial U$.

Comment: @DanielFischer    Thanks a million！ How to construct such a sequence compliance with requirements？

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask. I'll make a guess. Let $S = \sup \{ \lvert f(z)\rvert : z \in U\}$. (A priori, $S$ might be $+\infty$.) By definition of $\sup$, there is a sequence $(z_n)$ in $U$ with $\lvert f(z_n)\rvert \to S$. Then $\lvert f(z_{n_k})\rvert \to S$ also for every subsequence $(z_{n_k})$. Now either $\lvert z_n\rvert \to \infty$, in which case we have $S\leqslant M$ from the assumption, or $(z_n)$ contains a subsequence that converges to some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. Then we may as well assume that the full sequence does, to avoid the double subscripts.

Comment: Now $z_0 \in \overline{U}$ since the $z_n$ lie in $U$. But $z_0 \in U$ is impossible, since $\lvert f(z)\rvert < S$ for all $z \in U$ because $f$ isn't constant. Hence $z_0 \in \partial U$. And again it follows that $S \leqslant M$ from the assumption.

Comment: Sincere thanks for your help